# Preventing JXTable from automatically adjusting column widths

Tags: java, jtable, swingx, tablecolumn, jxtable

There's a specific scenario I've run into with JXTable (maybe its even a JTable issue) regarding what happens AFTER I execute a 'Pack All Columns' call.

'Pack All Columns' works fine, but when I then manually make a column width smaller, upon the next TableModelEvent received, the column width I modified is then always made LARGER. I notice that JTable's private setWidthsFromPreferredWidths() is ultimately called which looks like the culprit.

Again, this issue only occurs after I select 'Pack All Columns'. Is this a known bug or is this the intended behavior of 'Pack All Columns'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer to my question at http://www.coderanch.com/

It involved overriding the **columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent)** method to ensure the **getWidth()** and **getPreferredWidth()** of a column were in sync:

```
@Override
public void columnMarginChanged(final ChangeEvent e)
{
    super.columnMarginChanged(e);

    if (isEditing())
    {
        removeEditor();
    }
    TableColumn resizingColumn = null;
    if (tableHeader != null)
    {
        resizingColumn = tableHeader.getResizingColumn();
    }
    if (resizingColumn != null)
    {
        if (autoResizeMode == AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)
        {
            resizingColumn.setPreferredWidth(resizingColumn.getWidth());
        }
        else
        { 
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    doLayout();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }
}
```